# Models of PA inside a computationally weaker theory

Tags: logic, set-theory, arithmetic, model-theory, computability

I have two questions about the computability power of theories, one about models of ${PA}$ and the other about the model theory itself:

1. Is it possible to create a model of ${PA}$ inside a weaker theory in that all recursive/computable functions are not representable?
2. How much of ${ZFC}$ do we need to develop a semantics theory? I mean a standard theory that says ${X}$ is a model of ${Y}$, in which we interpret other theories. Does this semantics theory necessarily represents all recursive functions?

Edit: I assumed that a theory in 1 is always some kind of set theory in which we can construct an algebraic structure to be counted as a model. I also assumed that a standard semantics theory has enough power to represent all natural numbers (for example, to be able to enumerate variables of language), so we can define representability just like the definition of representability of recursive functions for arithmetic.

Comment: A quick answer to 1. Yes. It suffices that your weak theory models the $\Pi_1$ consequences of PA.

Comment: You should ask only one question per post. And both of your questions here need clarification. 1. What exactly do you mean by "create a model of PA inside a theory $T$" (especially when $T$ is not a set theory)? 2. This depends on what properties you want your semantics theory to have. It takes very very little to *define* the standard semantics for first-order logic, but if you want to prove things about it (e.g. the completeness theorem), you'll need to assume a lot more. Finally, what does it mean for a semantics theory to represent all recursive functions?

Comment: @AlexKruckman For 1. I assumed that T is always some kind of set theory in which we can construct an algebraic structure to be counted as a model. for 2. I also assumed that a standard semantics theory has enough power to represent all natural numbers (for example, to be able to enumerate variables of language). so the definition of representability is just like the way we define it for arithmetic.